# Liquid Code Remove Everything Before First Pipe Instance In a Array with Two Pipes

Tags: split, shopify, liquid

99% of our Shopify product titles look like this:

**Brand Name | Product Name**

I have added liquid code to remove the Brand Name and "|" pipe character:

```
{% assign product_title_trim = product.title |  split: "| " %}
{{product_title_trim[1]}}
```

This successfully removes the Brand Name and pipe leaving just "Product Name".

The issue is we have some products whose titles look like this:

**Brand Name | Product Name | Variant Large**

The goal is to 1. Remove the Brand Name, 2. Remove the First and Second Pipe "|", and 3. Keep the "Variant Large". The final title would look like this:

**Product Name Variant Large**

I know I need to 1. First split the array at the desired location ('Brand Name | '), 2. After the Array is split and the title is **Product Name | Variant**, remove the first pipe instance. Removing everything before the first, *original* pipe instance is proving to be more of a challenge. It is simple to do with a title with only *one* pipe. How can I remove everything before the first pipe instance, but leave the second pipe instance intact? Then, I can easily remove the second pipe instance. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split` and `slice` filters from the liquid code to get the desired result.
You can also read more about these filters in the documentation:

[split](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/string-filters#split)

[slice](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/string-filters#slice)

Use like this:

```
{{ product.title | split: '|' | slice: 1, 2 }}
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully! Thank you! I had a feeling it would be something to do with the slice function.